# Include correct label with \includepdf

Tags: pdftex

I'm using the `\includepdf` command for adding appendices to my thesis.

```
\newpage
\includepdf[pagecommand={},scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Document for \gls{dpia}}
]{appendices/DPIA-geoparsing.pdf}
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pagecommand={},pages=2-]{appendices/DPIA-geoparsing.pdf}
\label{appendix:dpia}
```

The label doesn't work correctly it's referencing a different appendix. Is it possible to use labels like this on `\includepdf`? If not how can I correctly label my PDF.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a way to do it:

```
\includepdf[pagecommand={},scale=0.8,pages=1,pagecommand=\section{Document for \gls{dpia} \label{appendix:dpia}}
]{appendices/DPIA-geoparsing.pdf}
\includepdf[scale=0.8,pagecommand={},pages=2-]{appendices/DPIA-geoparsing.pdf}
```

By including the label as part of the section in the `pagecommand`.

Answer (score 1):

Labels are supported by the `includepdf` command, if you add the PDF to the table of contents (TOC) or another list, using either the `addtotoc` or `addtolist` options:

```
The PDF is inserted on page \pageref{fileLabel}.

\includepedf[
    pages=-,
    addtotoc={1, section, 1, This title in TOC + header, fileLabel}
    ]{file.pdf}
```

See the [manual](https://texdoc.org/serve/pdfpages.pdf/0) for more on the two options.